# How to identify user account in DBA_SYS_PRIVS table in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, audit

I'm trying to look for all the users with certain privileges in the DBA_SYS_PRIVS table. The table has a GRANTEE column and according to Oracle Official website, the GRANTEE column shows "Grantee name, user, or role receiving the grant". So how could I know if the GRANTEE is an account or a role? For example, there is role called SYS and also an account called SYS in the Oracle DB. So how do I know if this is an account or role????

Also in table DBA_TAB_PRIVS, there is a column called GRANTEE. And in this table, the column GRANTEE is "Name of the user to whom access was granted". So I am really confused because the "GRANTEE" column means different things in two different tables

Please help, thanksssssssssssssss

Comment: By default, there is no role `SYS`.  I wouldn't expect it to be possible to create a role with the same name as a user but I haven't tried.  Are you saying that you see a row in `dba_roles` where the `role` is SYS?

Comment: Well, maybe SYS is a wrong example. But I saw "DBA" under GRANTEE column in the DBA_SYS_PRIVS. So is this point to the DBA role or the name of the account is 'DBA'?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no `SYS` role in Oracle.

```
 SQL> select * from dba_roles where role='SYS';

 no rows selected
```

Actually you cant create roles same name as usernames.

```
 SQL> create role sys;
 create role sys
        *
 ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01921: role name 'SYS' conflicts with another user or role name
```

To get only the roles without usernames.

```
SQL>select grantee from dba_sys_privs where grantee not in(select username from all_users);
```

To get only users without roles.

```
 SQL>select grantee from dba_sys_privs where grantee in(select username from all_users)
```

Comment: What about 'DBA' role? In the "SYS_USERS" table, you can see the DBA accounts under Name Column and there is also a GRANTEE called DBA in DBA_SYS_PRIVS table?

Comment: `DBA` is not a user, its role. `select username from all_users where username='DBA'` what do you get?